# InboxSDK ModalView doesn't trigger inner events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, inboxsdk

I met a strange issue. The issue comes from ModalView in InboxSDK, that is just list items what doesn't trigger click events. The code lines are like as below:

```
const openAutoReplyView = () => {
    const el = document.createElement('div');
    el.innerHTML = AutoReplyPage();
    const btn_insert_template = el.querySelector('#btn-insert-template');
    console.log(btn_insert_template);
    btn_insert_template.addEventListener('click', (e) => {      
      console.log(e);
    });
    // btn_insert_template.click();
    const replyModal = sdk.Widgets.showModalView({
      title: "Automail Reply",
      chrome: true,
      el: el
    });
    console.log(replyModal)
}

// auto-reply-page.js
export const AutoReplyPage = () => `
...
<div class='flex items-center mt-6'>
    ...
    <div class="dropdown border border-gray-300">
        ${IconButton("mnu-template", ComposeIcon())}
        <ul class="dropdown-content p-3" style="width: 120px;">
            <div class="dropdown-content-header">Template</div>
            ${TemplateDropdown.map((item) => ("<li>"+ MenuItem(item.id, item.children) +"</li>")).join('')}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div> 
`

// menu-item.js
export const MenuItem = (id, children) => `
<a id="${id}">${children}</a>
`
```